# What's the equivalent for "rpm -qf <FILE>" with the Python rpm library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rpm

```
# rpm -qf /usr/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/six.py
python3-six-1.12.0-r0
```

How do I use Python to query which package the file belongs to?

Comment: Any information on the OS you're using? I'm guessing given you've equated RPM with package-manager you're on Red Hat or Amazon Linux or something...

Comment: https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch16s03s02.html

Answer (score 0):

I've not found a direct call to the rpm database that gives in return the package providing a given file, so the better solution I've right now is the following:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import rpm

CHECK_FILE = "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/six.py"

ts = rpm.TransactionSet()
mi = ts.dbMatch()
for h in mi:
    files = h['FILENAMES']
    if CHECK_FILE in files:
        print("{}-{}-{}".format(h['name'], h['version'], h['release']))
        break
```